# How do i display an variable from a switch statement on my ASP.NET page?

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc-3, switch-statement

I'm trying to display the month from a datetime object in text so that it looks like this:

> 01 Dec 2011

I've created a `switch` statement to identify the month and put the string into a variable I want to display on my index.aspx page. However, it doesn't seem to work and I'm not sure why.

```
<% 
string month = "";
switch(item.postdate.Month)
{
    case(1):
        month = "Jan";
        break;

    case(2):
        month = "Feb";
        break;

    case(3):
        month = "Mar";
        break;

    case(4):
        month = "Apr";
        break;

    case(5):
        month = "Maj";
        break; 

    case(6):
        month = "jun";
        break;

    case(7):
        month = "Jul";
        break;

    case(8):
        month = "Aug";
        break;

    case(9):
        month = "Sep";
        break;

    case(10):
        month = "Okt";
        break; 

    case(11):
        month = "Nov";
        break; 

    case(12):
        month = "Dec";
        break;
};
Html.Display(month);
%>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try:

```
<%: item.postdate.ToString("dd MMM yyyy") %>
```

Or if you just want the name in a string

```
string month = item.postdate.ToString("MMM")
```

More information about [`DateTime.ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Do you have a full datetime object?

If so you can use:

```
dateObject.ToString("dd MMM yyyy");
```

Comment: that solved it without all my stupid workarrounds. thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Whats wrong with just formatting the date how you want?

```
var dateAsString = item.postDate.ToString("MMM");
```

see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Can't you just use DateTime.ToString() Patterns?

You can read up on it [here](http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm)